# Material Properties Dealing with "Wetting"

Tags: water, materials

I am designing a rain device, and I am interested in a set of common metrics / standards for determining how something gets "wet".

(1) Is there a "water absorbance" metric for materials (ie will the water be deflected or actually penetrate the surface)

(2) Ability for the material to dry (I know this is measured in time, but is there a standard for the drying conditions)

If you know of any other standards that may be of interest please let me know.

Comment: Search contact angle measurements for surfaces.

Comment: The contact angle deals with hydrophily/hydrophoby. This is a sort of skin properties. But from the text It might be that you also look for something actual, like the weight of water absorbed for a given surface/volume.